# How to dynamically create an expression using javascript and alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to create a conditional menu in a datatable. For some records the menu will appear, in other cases it will not. My backend (PHP) sends the following parameters to the frontend:

```
['field' => 'blocked_at', 'operator' => '!==', 'value' => null]
```

or

```
['field' => 'blocked_at', 'operator' => '===', 'value' => null]
```

So in HTML I call the function

```
<template x-if="checkConditions(record[action.conditions.field], action.conditions.operator, action.conditions.value)">
 <a href="#!" class="dropdown-item" x-on:click="runAction(action, record[action.keyfield])">
  <i x-bind:class="action.icon"></i><span x-text="action.label"></span>
 </a>
</template>
```

function in Alpine.js

```
checkConditions (field, operator, value) {
 let condition = `${field} ${operator} ${value} ? true : false`;
 return eval(condition);
},
```

But it doesn't work, I'm getting the error "identifier starts immediately after numeric literal". I don't know why this happens. There is an error in the checkConditions function.

Could you help me solve this challenge?

Comment: The entire `let` statement is off. What is the condition you actually need?

Comment: why is it off? I can see the values with console.log, but then the error is thrown. An example: value of variable 'field' is 2022-02-15, value of variable 'operator' is ===, value of variable 'value' is null. I needs that js execute this statement (**2022-02-15 === null ? true : false**) and returt true or false. Did you undersand?

Comment: The `2022-02-15 === null ` is not valid JS, you need to add quotation marks around the date. This `eval` usage is kinda error prone, because you need to treat strings and number etc. differently. Why don't you check the condition on the backend and pass just a `true/false` variable to the frontend?